# Combine a shell script and a zip file into a single executable for deployment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, deployment

I have two files for deployment,

1) `deploymentpackage.zip` -> It contains the database package with few shell scripts.

2) `deployment.sh` -> It is the primary shell script which first unzips the deploymentpackage.zip and then execute the list of shell files inside it.

It is working as expected.

But what I need is, I need to make the zip file as executable so that I dont want to deliver both `deploymentpackage.zip` and `deployment.sh` to client.

So Is it possible to make the `deploymentpackage.zip` as executable so that I don't want to have another script deployment.sh.

Expectation : Running this `deploymentpackage.zip` should unzip the same file and run the list of scripts inside it.

Comment: You can append the zip file to a script that separates and unpacks the zip file.

Comment: I'd investigate using a shell script running unzip and feed a bash 'heredoc' into this. You can then simply download/execute a (admittedly sizeable) shell script to achieve your aim

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's ok to assume that the user who will run the script has the `unzip` utility, then you can create a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# commands that you need to do ...
# ...

unzip <(tail -n +$((LINENO + 2)) "$0")
exit
```

Make sure the script has a newline `\n` character at the end of the line of `exit`. And, it's important that the last line of the script is the `exit` command, and that the `unzip` command with `tail` is right in front of it.

Then, you can append to this file the zipped content, for example with:

```
cat file.zip >> installer.sh
```

Users will be able to run `installer.sh`, which will `unzip` the zipped content at the end of the file.

Comment: OP wants "It is the primary shell script which first unzips the deploymentpackage.zip and then execute the list of shell files inside it.". The script can be changed that it is unzipped in `/tmp/somedir` and execute the file `/tmp/somedir/deployment.sh`. I agree with @peter_stimpel that you must really trust the inputfile.

Answer (score -1):

Write a readme file, and ask your users to chmod the script, then to execute it.

For security reason I hope there is no way to auto-execute such things...

Edit: received a vote down because the OP did not like it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: You may assume who downvoted and why, but you cannot really know, can you. I suggest to not make statements like that. I downvoted it because I think it doesn't answer the question, and I find it not useful.