# How to deploy a shell script to private linux vm

Tags: linux, bash, azure

I have a private Azure Linux VM means it can be accessed only from jumpbox(access) vm. I need to deploy a script to this private VM. As this VM cannot even access any storage account/repo, I can't use `Custom Script Extension` for script deployment. So I thought of deploying the script using `az vm run-command invoke` by converting the `SomeScript.sh` to strings and `echo` it to the virtual machine. Different pieces of my code as below:

```
SomeScript.sh
#!/bin/bash

#
# CommandToExecute: ./SomeScript.sh ${CUST_NO}
#
#some more code
```

Function that converts the .sh file to strings:

```
function getCommandToExecute()
{
    local scriptName=$1
    local commandToExecute
    local currentLocation=$(dirname "$0")
    local scriptFullPath="$currentLocation/Environment/VmScripts/$scriptName"
    mapfile < $scriptFullPath
    printf -v escapedContents "%q\n" "${MAPFILE[@]}"
    commandToExecute+="echo "$escapedContents" > /usr/myapps/$scriptName"
    echo "$commandToExecute"
}
```

vm run command:

```
az vm run-command invoke -g $resourceGroupName \
-n $vmName --command-id RunShellScript \
--scripts "#!/bin/bash\n ${commandToExecute}"
```

If I use the `"#!/bin/bash\n ${commandToExecute}"` part (`commandToExecute` replaced with string scripts)  in the `RunCommand` window in azure portal, the script works fine, but I can't make it work via run command due to this exception:
`\n[stdout]\n\n[stderr]\n/bin/sh: 1: /var/lib/waagent/run-command/download/133/script.sh: not found\n"`

Any idea what is missing here? Or if there is a better alternative to handle this.

Comment: The [documentation of az vm run-command invoke --scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-invoke) states *`Use @{file} to load script from a file`*. It is unclear whether `file` has to be on the client side or server side. Could you give it a shot and report the results? `az vm run-command invoke ... --scripts '@{scriptFileOnYourLocalMachine}'`.

Comment: @Socowi I think `@{scriptFileOnYourLocalMachine}` is for runnning a script on vm, but I am looking for deploying the `SomeScript.sh` on the VM so that other authorized users  execute commands like `SomeScript.sh ${CUST_NO}` on same vm.

Comment: Thank you for ruling out possible misunderstandings. I should have pointed out that I wanted to create a solution that does [`@{deployMyScript.sh}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62361755/6770384) and not `@{scriptToBeDeployed.sh}`. I just needed to know whether `@{file}` references files from the local host or files from the remote host. The name `(any)scriptFileOnYourLocalMachine` was a bit misleading, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think quoting the whole script and its deployment script for use with `--scripts` is a lot of work and error prone too. Luckily, there are easier alternatives for both quoting steps. The [documentation of `az vm run-command invoke --scripts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-run-command-invoke) states

> Use `@{file}` to load script from a file.

Therefore, you can do

```
deploymentScript() {
  echo   '#! /usr/bin/env bash'
  printf 'tail -n+4 "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" > %q\n' "$2"
  echo   'exit'
  cat "$1"
}
deploymentScript local.sh remote.sh > tmpDeploy.sh
az vm run-command invoke ... --scripts '@{tmpDeploy.sh}'
rm tmpDeploy.sh
```

Replace `local.sh` with the path of the local script you want to deploy and replace `remote.sh` with the remote path where the script should be deployed.

If you are lucky, then you might not even need `tmpDeploy.sh`. Try

```
az vm ... --scripts "@{<(deploymentScript local.sh remote.sh)}"
```

Some notes on the implementation:

- The deployed script is an exact copy of your script file. Even embedded binary data is kept. The trick with `tail $BASH_SOURCE` is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351570/6770384).
- The script can be arbitrarily long. Even huge scripts won't run into the error `Argument list too long` imposed by `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Comment: That worked !!! :). I didn't use `tmpDeploy.sh`, so I changed the the syntax to `--scripts "$(deploymentScript $scriptFullPath /usr/local/bin/$scriptName)"` as `@` is for `.sh` file. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

There was issue with escaped string I mentioned above. After correcting the code, it all good now. My final code:

```
function getCommandToExecute()
{
    local scriptName=$1
    local commandToExecute
    local currentLocation=$(dirname "$0")
    local scriptFullPath="$currentLocation/Environment/VmScripts/$scriptName"
    local singleStringCommand=""

    mapfile -t < $scriptFullPath
    for line in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; 
    do 
        singleStringCommand+="$(printf '%s' "$line" | sed 's/[\"$]/\\&/g')"
        singleStringCommand+="\n"
    done
    commandToExecute+="echo "\"$singleStringCommand\"" > /usr/local/bin/$scriptName;"
    echo "$commandToExecute" 
}
```